# Issue with simple product expression in CentOS 8 Linux

Tags: centos

I have CentOS 8 Linux, and i'm trying to evaluate a simple product expression as following:
`[root@localhost /]# expr 4 * 2`
I suppose to see `8` as an output in the bash terminal, however I'm getting the below syntax error
`expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘bin’`. What could be wrong in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shell is expanding `*`; it’s a glob which is replaced by the names of the files in the current directory. Since you’re running in `/`,

```
expr 4 * 2
```

becomes

```
expr 4 bin boot dev etc home lib ... 2
```

which causes the error.

You need to quote the operator, or escape it:

```
expr 4 "*" 2
expr 4 \* 2
```